# $f(t)= \frac{4e^{kt} - 1}{4e^{kt} +1}$, where $k$ is a positive constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function $f$ is defined by $f(t)= \frac{4e^{kt} - 1}{4e^{kt} +1}$, where $k$ is a positive constant.

(a) Show that $f'(t)>0$.

(b ) Show that $k(1- [f(t)]^2) = 2f'(t)$ and, hence, show that $f''(t)<0$.

Comment: can you use $$\LaTeX$$ please?

Comment: What formulas for computing derivatives have you learned? Do you know the derivative of $e^{kt}$? Try writing the formula for $f'(t)$, it looks like you will need it for part (b) and it may be the easiest way to do part (a) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

differentiating $$f(t)$$ with respect to $$t$$ we get after simplification $$f'(t)=8\,{\frac {k{{\rm e}^{kt}}}{ \left( 4\,{{\rm e}^{kt}}+1 \right) ^{2}}}$$
since $k>0$ and the exponential function is poesitive we get $$f'(t)>0$$ for all $t$
simplifying the equation $$k(1-f(t)^2)$$ we obtain $$16\,{\frac {k{{\rm e}^{kt}}}{ \left( 4\,{{\rm e}^{kt}}+1 \right) ^{2}}
}
$$ and this is $$2f'(t)$$ and we get for the second derivative as $$f''(t)=-8\,{\frac {{k}^{2}{{\rm e}^{kt}} \left( 4\,{{\rm e}^{kt}}-1 \right) 
}{ \left( 4\,{{\rm e}^{kt}}+1 \right) ^{3}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

(a)$$f'(t)=\frac{(4e^{kt}-1)' \cdot (4e^{kt}+1)-(4e^{kt}-1)\cdot(4e^{kt}+1)'}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{4ke^{kt}(4e^{kt}+1)-4ke^{kt}(4e^{kt}-1)}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{16ke^{2kt}+4ke^{kt}-16ke^{2kt}+4e^{kt}}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{8ke^{kt}}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}>0$$
since $k$ is a positive constant.

(b)$$k(1-f(t)^2)=k\Bigl(1-\frac{(4ke^{kt}-1)^2}{(4ke^{kt}+1)^2}\Bigr)$$
$$=k\Bigl(\frac{(4e^{kt}+1)^2-(4e^{kt}-1)^2}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}\Bigr)$$
$$=k\Bigl(\frac{(4e^{kt}+1+4^{kt}-1)\cdot(4e^{kt}+1-4e^{kt}+1)}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}\Bigr)$$
$$=k\cdot\frac{8e^{kt} \cdot 2}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{16ke^{kt}}{(4e^{kt}+1)^2}=2 \cdot f'(t)$$

Also,

$$f''(t)=\frac{(8ke^{kt})' \cdot (4e^{kt}+1)^2 - (8ke^{kt}) \cdot [(4e^{kt}+1)^2]'}{(4e^{kt}+1)^4}$$
$$=\frac{8k^2e^{kt}(4e^{kt}+1)^2-(8ke^{kt})\cdot\bigl(2\cdot(4e^{kt}+1)\cdot(4e^{kt}+1)'\bigr)}{(4e^{kt}+1)^4}$$
$$=\frac{8k^2e^{kt}\cdot(4e^{kt}+1)^2-16ke^{kt}\cdot (4e^{kt}+1)(4ke^{kt})}{(4e^{kt}+1)^4}$$
$$=\frac{8k^2e^{kt}(4ke^{kt}+1)-16ke^{kt} \cdot 4ke^{kt}}{(4e^{kt}+1)^3}$$
$$=\frac{8k^2e^{kt}[4e^{kt}+1-8e^{kt}]}{(4e^{kt}+1)^3}$$
$$\frac{8k^2e^{kt}(-4e^{kt}+1)}{(4e^{kt}+1)^3}<0$$
since $-4e^{kt}+1<0$.